# How to loop "If Then" x number of times or rerun until condition is met?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Remove()


Dim thiswb As Workbook

Dim x As Integer

Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook

Lastrow = thiswb.Worksheets("Pool Factor Adj").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
x = 1

Do Until x = 5

For i = Lastrow To 3 Step by - 1

If (thiswb.Worksheets("Pool Factor Adj").Cells(i, 1).Value) = "TradeID" Then

Range("A" & Lastrow & ":I" & Lastrow).Delete

End If

x = x + 1

Next
Loop

End Sub
```

The IF Then part works as it deletes the last row if there is "TradeID" in the one of the rows. How can I loop this x number of times rather than rerunning the macro manually? Or how can I loop it until it no longer finds "TradeID" in one of the rows?

Comment: `Lastrow` is the upper bound and will not change for the duration of the loop, you probably need to reference the `i` variable which is the index. (10,9,8 etc).

Comment: Are you just trying to delete all rows where column A contains "TradeID"?

Comment: `Range("A" & Lastrow & ":I" & Lastrow).Delete` will always delete the last row as defined in the `LastRow = thiswb.worksheets....` line.  Use `Range("A" & i & ":I" & i).Delete` to delete the row being looked at in the loop.... edit.... that's what @KostasK. said.  Sorry. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Delete Criteria Rows (A Simple Loop)

**Before**

[image]

- The code will delete a limited amount (5) of the bottom-most criteria rows (yellow).

**After 1 (5 rows deleted)**

[image]

- If the number of criteria rows (3) is less than the amount (5), all rows (3) will be deleted (blue).

**After 2 (8 rows deleted)**

[image]

**The Code**

- No `Union`, no arrays, no `AutoFilter` i.e. no 'techniques' are used to increase efficiency.
- The first code uses constants at the beginning illustrating how easy it is to change their values in one place instead of searching for them in the code (note that the code could be much longer and there could be multiple occurrences of some of the constants or some constants could have the same values at some point, making it painful to change their values).

```vb
Sub DeleteCriteriaRows()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Pool Factor Adj"
    Const DeleteRowsCount As Long = 5
    Const FirstRow As Long = 3
    Const LastRowColumn As String = "A"
    Const CriteriaColumn As String = "A"
    Const DeleteColumns As String = "A:I"
    Const Criteria As String = "TradeID"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, LastRowColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    For r = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
        Set rCell = ws.Cells(r, CriteriaColumn)
        If StrComp(CStr(rCell.Value), Criteria, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            rCell.EntireRow.Columns(DeleteColumns).Delete xlShiftUp
            rCount = rCount + 1
        End If
        If rCount = DeleteRowsCount Then Exit For
    Next

    MsgBox "Criteria rows deleted: " & rCount, vbInformation

End Sub

Sub DeleteCriteriaRowsNoConstants()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pool Factor Adj")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    For r = LastRow To 3 Step -1
        Set rCell = ws.Cells(r, "A")
        If StrComp(CStr(rCell.Value), "TradeID", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            rCell.EntireRow.Columns("A:I").Delete xlShiftUp
            rCount = rCount + 1
        End If
        If rCount = 5 Then Exit For
    Next

    MsgBox "Criteria rows deleted: " & rCount, vbInformation

End Sub
```